# How to export Google Chrome bookmarks

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks

I have got Google Chrome (Version 41.0.2272.118 (64-bit)) and I would like to export my bookmarks without having to sync anything with any online accounts. I read [here](https://superuser.com/a/158441) that the bookmarks are stored here:

```
~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Bookmarks
```

So do I just take a copy of that file then and paste its contents into another Chrome installation? Or is there more to it than that? Or perhaps and easier way of doing this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Google Chrome type `chrome://bookmarks/` into the address bar to open the Bookmark Manager. From here the process is different dependant on what version of the Bookmark Manager you are using. If you are using the new interface click on the cog icon in the left corner of the page and select "Export bookmarks...":

[image: Google Chrome Bookmarks]

If you are using the older version of the Bookmark Manager click on the Organise tab and select "Export bookmarks to HTML file":

[image: Old Google Chrome Bookmarks]

This will allow you to export your bookmarks as an HTML file and you will be able to import them again at a later date.

Comment: Backup manually by exporting the files to HTML or CVS file, or backup automatically with third-party softwares, which can save time. Checkout https://www.easeus.com/backup-recovery/backup-chrome-bookmarks-and-passwords.html

Answer (score 6):

## Official Way

### Export bookmarks from Chrome

1. In the top-right corner of the browser window, click the Chrome menu Chrome menu.
2. Select Bookmarks > Bookmark Manager.
3. Click the "Organize" menu in the manager.  Don't see the "Organize"
   menu? Try using the alternate directions below.
4. Select Export bookmarks. Chrome will export your bookmarks as an HTML file, which you can then import into another browser.

### Alternate directions

1. In the top-right corner of the Chrome browser window, click the
   Chrome menu Chrome menu.
2. Select Bookmarks > Bookmark Manager.
3. In the top-right corner of the Bookmark Manager, click the gear button.
4. Select Export bookmarks.

In this way, you should also be able to import bookmarks into other browsers (tested only on firefox).

Source
https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/96816?hl=en

## Nerd way

As you said, you can always copy the content of

```
~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Bookmarks
```

and then past it into another `google-chrome` installation.
Note that you can also use this file interchangeably with the `chromium` analogous; in this case, the location of the file is the pretty straightforward

```
~/.config/chromium/Default/Bookmarks
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to copy the full directory to your new PC:

```
~/.config/google-chrome/
```

It should work.

Answer (score 0):

Find and open a bookmarks.html file.
When you see the list of bookmarks, use Control-A to mark them all.
Now place your cursor on the bookmarks toolbar; Use Control-C to copy all.
This worked for me.  Benrus