# How to recover Chrome bookmarks from old hard drive

Tags: google-chrome, data-recovery, bookmarks

My computer (Ubuntu 18) is unable to boot so I decided to do a clean install.  I have my bookmarks backed up but only from about 3 weeks ago and I'd like to recover some that I saved in the last two weeks.

Accessing my old files using only Ubuntu on the thumb drive, where can I find the Chrome bookmarks file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to export Google Chrome bookmarks](https://askubuntu.com/questions/607801/how-to-export-google-chrome-bookmarks)

Comment: No, that shows how to export bookmarks if you have access to your computer.  In my case, Ubuntu crashed and I could only access my hard drive using Ubuntu through the USB stick.  I had access to my drive this way but was not able to open Chrome to export.  Is it possible to export bookmarks using Ubuntu on a thumb drive?

Comment: Read the other answers like [this one](https://askubuntu.com/a/607803/167115) and [this one](https://askubuntu.com/a/607804/167115). It shows the path to the file you need to copy manually. The location isn't going to be `~/` of course, so it will be something like `/home/76767676/.config/google-chrome/Default/Bookmarks` on the hard drive which you can access using the USB live session of Ubuntu. The full path will not start with `/home` however, it will be indexed under wherever the drive is mounted.

Comment: I've seen answers like this but I have no idea where to find ~

~/.config/google-chrome/

Is the ~ some location I'm supposed to know about already because in looking at the drive I don't see anything that starts with ~

Comment: The tilde `~` represents `/home/username` where `username` is your actual username. So you can probably locate your `Videos` folder and your `Music` folder. These are located at `~/Videos` which is the same as `/home/username/Videos` where `username` is your actual username. Also, be aware that the `.config` folder is hidden because there is a period at the beginning of the directory name so you have to set your file browser to show hidden files.

Comment: So, on that drive, the directory is `/home/username/.config/google-chrome/Default/Bookmarks` where `username` is the actual username you were using on your old Ubuntu system. Be sure you have your file browser set to show hidden files and directories.

Comment: Can you find your old `Videos` or `Downloads` directory on the drive you are trying to access? These are in your old user's home directory. The `.config` directory is also in your old user's home directory. Again, be sure you have it set to show hidden files.

Comment: In a terminal you can try : `find ~/.config/google-chrome -type f -name Bookmarks` and just in case you use Chromium `find ~/.config/chromium -type f -name Bookmarks`

Comment: Thanks mchid!  I could never find the .config and I didn't realize they were hidden.  I opened 'view' 'show hidden files' and there they are!  :-)  By the way, if you make it an answer I'll select it. ;-)

Comment: You can also answer your own question to give details of the steps you took to restore the bookmarks to help someone else in the future